# How to cut and audio file on ubuntu 22.04 from cli?

Tags: 22.04, audio-player

I tried to cut an audio file using cli, giving start time and end time, unsuccessfully on ubuntu 22.04 using:

- avconv (couldn't install it)
- avplay (couldn't install it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:50:00 -i input.mp3 output.mp3
```

-ss: start time

-t end time